# Ошибка совместимости типов

Tags: c++, double, типы, совместимость

Я хочу объявить тип **long long double** , но компилятор выдает ошибку, так как для него это все равно,что  объявление **int double**. Можно ли все-таки объявить переменную **long long double** как -нибудь?

```
long long double f = 17.8281// Не получается
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос метку языка и ваш пример, а то `int double` это как-то дико :)

Comment: Ну ,хорошо, язык c++

Comment: А что по вашему данная конструкция должна обозначать для компилятора?

Comment: Что это за число такое должно быть?

Comment: Автор, вот тут таблица типов: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types . Самое близкое это, наверное, `long double`, но у вас в вопросе такое маленькое число, что и простого `float` хватит за глаза

Comment: @gil9red ,ну, я примерно привел пример. Конечно, число планируется выбрать большее для максимальной точности

Comment: просто нет такого типа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Язык имеет точно указанные фундаментальные типы, и читерство тут не проходит. От того, что вы напишете `long long long`, размер типа не вырастет до 12 байт...

Более того, стандарт не гарантирует, что `long double` будет больше и точнее, чем `double` - только то, что его размер будет не меньше (а сюда входит и понятие равенства), чем у `double`.

Так что если вам *действительно* нужен (а не *кажется*, что нужен) такой "большой" тип - то вы можете или взять готовую библиотеку для работы с такими особо большими и точными числами, или написать свой тип...

Comment: Да, люди выше дали уже это понять